# Completely clear all cloud music from iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, music

I'm trying to get rid of all of the cloud music from my iPhone 6S on iOS 10.2.1.

So far I have:

Gone to Settings>iTunes & App Store> and toggled Automatic Downloads> Music
Gone to Settings>Music and:

- turned off (and on and off again) "Show Apple Music"
- turned off Mobile data.
- gone to "Downloaded Music" and selected to delete all songs - now shows "Zero KB"
- Signed out of home sharing

I have signed out from my apple ID. I have signed out under Settings>iCloud.

I have deleted all playlists.

After all of this I have rebooted the phone.

I have tried everything I can think of and when I go to Music> Library or Songs I still see a few hundred songs with the cloud download icon next to them.

Is the only way to delete them individually? This whole system is a joke. I have looked at the similar questions here and have not found an answer that works.

Comment: See also here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194351/how-to-clear-new-music-apps-cache-of-streaming-music-on-ios

Answer (score -1):

The most recent version of iOS I have used is 7.1.2, but in that version you have to go to Settings>iCloud>`Account Name`>Delete All Data, and then sign out. It still may not fully work, so you should also log in to your Apple account in your browser (or go to Settings>iCloud if you have a Mac), open the list of devices associated with your account, and remove the iPhone. Finally you may want to change your account password to make sure the device cant be auto added to the account when it reconnects to the internet.

I will be the first to agree that their forced integration of iCloud and refusal to let you remove it is crap. For this reason I might also recommend jailbreaking if you're okay with it. Once an iDevice is jailbroken you can install iFile and manually delete the songs from the iCloud music folder. Be careful though because deleting the folder itself could cause problems.

Comment: I already have No Devices showing in iCloud.

Comment: Had you already performed/have you tried any of the other steps in my answer? Also, did you use the option to delete all data associated with your account from the phone *before* you signed out? I also find it strange that you would not at least see the device you were currently signed in on in your list of iCloud devices, given that is to be expected.

Comment: This question is about iCloud music library. Not deleting all iCloud data.